# Find the number of 2's between 0 and n

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Find the number of 2's between 0 and n?

The way I thought is to count how many 2's are there of length k(number of digits in n).

This is similar to find all permutation of digit[0-9] of length k that have at least one 2 in it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... but what do you mean by 'find the number of 2s'?

Comment: let say n = 12 so {1,2,3..............12} in this 2 is occurred at 2 and and 12 so total number of 2's is 2

Comment: What would the answer be for $n=50$?

Comment: 16, 1 between{1 to 10}, 2 between{11,20},11 between{21,30}, 1 between{31,40}, 1 between {41,50}. 1+2+11+1+1 = 16

Comment: If $n$ is a power of 10 a formula wouldn't be too hard to find but one that works for any possible $n$ would be very fiddly with lots of sub-cases.

Comment: I think this has come up elsewhere than the question I cited as well.

Comment: OK, then for $n=50$ the answer is 15 - five $2$s in unit position and ten $2$s in tens position - but I understand that you are simply counting occurrences of the digit in the numbers.